# Manga where the MC is reincarnated into a young boy who is also the future villain

Tags: story-identification, isekai

The MC one day finds himself in the body of the villain of the game he once played. However in the game the villain (which he is now), dies by the hero. He now has to use his knowledge of the game's story and lore, so he can keep the hero and story on the right path, as he changes the ending for himself.

The characters and setting around him all turn real, with no game mechanics. He, himself doesn't have any status either. He IS in a fantasy world, where it's the same as the game he use to play.

The young boy the mc turns into looks pretty much like any other mc you'll find, but looks more like a villain as he gets older. The mc is also a noble who can't say anything nice. The story forces himself to say rude things (example: thank you = my gratitude is wasted on you).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874) and [edit] in any extra info you can remember?

Comment: We really need more information. As noted in [this blog entry](https://toxicmuffin.wordpress.com/2018/07/31/help-im-evil/), this is an entire genre in itself. Is the game adventure fantasy? Romance? Magic academy? Science fiction?

Comment: Along the same vein, do the mechanics of the game change where he's transported in? Some *isekai* work just like a video game, with people aware of their hit points and skill ranks, and invoking skills by name (often in brackets as a convention). In others, they work more like traditional fantasy, sometimes with the protagonist being the only one who can see the game screens.

Comment: If it was a female, I would say "My Next Life as a Villainess: All Routes Lead to Doom!". But you did specify male, so not so sure. How it is possible that MNLV is a remake of the story you are thinking about.

Comment: I simple remember the story and want to find out if it updated. However, I can't remember the name of it so I can't find it. If you need more information, leave a comment and I'll do my best in answering.          P.S. please don't ask me the names of characters, I'm awful with names (what a surprise).

Comment: @user144131 - Is this full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the MC's hair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[My Death Flags Show No Sign Of Ending](https://myanimelist.net/manga/114150/My_Death_Flags_Show_No_Sign_of_Ending)*.

> An ordinary university student found everywhere, Hirasawa Kazuki, was in possession a game character’s body when he came to his senses. Moreover, it was Harold Stokes’, the story’s most hated figure who held the title 『King of Scum』. For him, tons of landmines appearing like death flags are in his surroundings! Can Kazuki evade the mountainous amount of death flags and advance through the survival route!?

That took forever to find. I finally found it by typing random words into the search bar, on the website I read manga.

[image: Front cover of My Death Flags Show No Sign Of Ending]

Comment: Congrats! How did you find it? And can you add some details to the answer to show how it matches, and to provide keywords that might allow future people to find it? Lastly, you can self-accept 48 hours after asking by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: I typed random words into the search bar, on the website I read manga.